# jQuery UI: nested droppables with greedy not working when accept returns false

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, nested, droppable, greedy

I am currently working on a gui editor where you can drag & drop different controls (like textboxes or radio buttons) into different panels (e.g. stack-panel or grid). I am using jQuery UI for this.

**So here is a szenario where I have some unwanted behaviour:**

I have two nested droppable `div` container and a draggable component. The draggable is inside of the inner `div` (e.g. a textbox that is inside of a stack-panel that is inside of a grid).

Because the draggable is already inside of the inner droppable container I don't want the inner container to accept the draggable, but the outer container should accept it (therefore I have a custom `accept` callback function). Of course the droppables have to be `greedy` so that the event is not bubbling up.

Here is a simplified fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uj07ub07/12/

**My problem**:

when I move the draggable slightly around so that it is still inside of the inner container the outer container gets the event and fires the `drop` callback although both droppables are `greedy` (this does not happen if the inner container accepts the draggable). the outer container should only fire `drop` if I move the draggable outside of the inner `div`.

(the jsfiddle example is simpliefied. In my real project I remove the draggable from the container in the drop callback and append it to the new container etc.)

I think that the `greedy` option does only work if `accept` returns true and is ignored if accept returns false - so the event is bubbling up although it is greedy.

Is this a bug or a feature of jQuery UI? Is there any way to accomplish what I need?

Thanks!